# Connecting to non local BlazeDS Server (Mobile Air)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, blazeds, host

I try to connect to a BlazeDS Server in Flash Builder 4.6 ... But the Problem is, I can't configurate the project for a server, which is not installed on my computer. What if the blaseDS is only reachable via web?